# Is there any function available in Danfo.js similar to pandas isin()

Tags: node.js, pandas, danfojs

I am working extensive data processing in nodejs. I found danfojs as a nice alternative to python Pandas. But facing some functionality lacking in comparison to Pandas.

**How to work out pandas isin() functionality in Danfojs ?**

**Example:**

I have the below DataFrame:

| id | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| asefwc | Abdullah | Cumilla |
| wefcss | Khairul | Jashore |
| erfegf | Jaman | Magura |
| ytttte | Najrul | Nowga |
| edqfgh | Latif | Chattagram |
| yutydg | Majhar | Rajshahi |

And the below Series:

| id |
| --- |
| wefcss |
| ytttte |
| yutydg |

**I want to get those rows of the Dataframe which id exists in the series**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an equivalent of pandas 'isin' but I've found a work around to solve this problem

```
const dfd = require("danfojs-node")
const data = [
    ['asefwc', 'Abdullah', 'Cumilla'],
    ['wefcss', 'Khairul', 'Jashore'],
    ['erfegf',  'Jaman', 'Magura']
]

const columns = ['id', 'name', 'address']

let df = new dfd.DataFrame(data, { columns })

let ids = df['id'].values // get all the column values

let allRowsToInclude = []

// idsToInclude is your Series
idsToInclude.forEach((idToInclude) => {
  const rowsToInclude = ids.flatMap((id, idx) => id === idToInclude ? idx : [])
  allRowsToInclude = allRowsToInclude.push(... rowsToInclude)
}

// creates a new df with filtered rows
let dfFinal = df.loc({rows: allRowsToInclude})
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no native equivalent to pandas `isin` yet.

However, you can do something pretty similar via a boolean mask on the dataframe rows:

```
import * as dfd from "danfojs";

let df = new dfd.DataFrame([
  {"id":"asefwc", "name":"Abdullah", "address":"Cumilla"},
  {"id":"wefcss", "name":"Khairul", "address":"Jashore"},
  {"id":"erfegf", "name":"Jaman", "address":"Magura"},
]);

let idToInclude = ["asefwc", "erfegf"];

// Filtered dataframe:
df.loc({
  rows: df["id"].values.map(x => idToInclude.includes(x))
}).print();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's worthy to explore **dfd.DataFrame.merge**, [dfd.DataFrame.merge](https://danfo.jsdata.org/api-reference/general-functions/danfo.merge), basically, choosing an specific *join* variant you are filtering data in an specific way.